# Call to undefined function sqlsrv_connect() when connecting to MSSQL from PHP 7.0

Tags: ubuntu-16.04, php-extension, sqlsrv

I installed the php 7.0 extensions sqlsrv and pdo_sqlsrv via PECL on my ubuntu 16.04 server in order to connect to a MSSQL database. After this, I restared the entire server.

When calling sqlsrv_connect, I receive the error "Call to undefined function sqlsrv_connect()". The connection string looks like:

```
$serverName = "serverName"; 
$connectionInfo = array( "Database"=>" ", "UID"=>" ", "PWD"=>" ");
$conn = sqlsrv_connect( $serverName, $connectionInfo);
```

I made some checks based on the information I found on google:

1. `php -m` shows sqlsrv and pdo_sqlsrv as modules
2. `php -i` shows that the php.ini file contains references to additional .ini files for the extensions: /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/sqlsrv.ini and /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/pdo_sqlsrv.ini
3. `cat /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/sqlsrv.ini` returns *extension=sqlsrv.so* which indicates that the .ini file references to the correct extension (same holds for pdo_sqlsrv)
4. `php-config --extension-dir` returns */usr/lib/php/20151012* and `ls -la /usr/lib/php/20151012` shows *-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  326816 Oct  5 14:55 sqlsrv.so* which indicates that the extension file is in the correct folder (same holds for pdo_sqlsrv)
5. `php -i | grep sqlsrv` returns

   `/etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/pdo_sqlsrv.ini,
   /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/sqlsrv.ini,
   Registered PHP Streams => https, ftps, compress.zlib, php, file, glob, data, http, ftp, sqlsrv, phar
   PDO drivers => sqlsrv, mysql, sqlite
   pdo_sqlsrv
   pdo_sqlsrv support => enabled
   pdo_sqlsrv.client_buffer_max_kb_size => 10240 => 10240
   pdo_sqlsrv.log_severity => 0 => 0
   sqlsrv
   sqlsrv support => enabled
   sqlsrv.ClientBufferMaxKBSize => 10240 => 10240
   sqlsrv.LogSeverity => 0 => 0
   sqlsrv.LogSubsystems => 0 => 0
   sqlsrv.WarningsReturnAsErrors => On => On`

Do you have any idea what causes this error and how to fix it? I am happy to provide more information if necessary.

Comment: Linux based PHP does not support the sqlsrv_* functions. Those are only provided by the Windows driver. FreeTDS will provide you with access to the old mssql_* functions.

Comment: Microsoft released this PHP extension for Linux in 2017. Please compare "Create PHP apps using SQL Server on Ubuntu" https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/sql-server/developer-get-started/php/ubuntu/step/2.html

Comment: Did you install the extension using these commands? `sudo pecl7.X-sp install sqlsrv` and `sudo pecl7.X-sp install pdo_sqlsrv`

Comment: If so, did you restart the apache service?

Comment: No, I installed it as "sudo pecl install sqlsrv pdo_sqlsrv" and restarted the entire server. edit: of course added the extension to the .ini file before

Comment: Can you add to your question the output of the following command `php7.X-sp -i | grep -i sqlsrv`

Comment: I tried this "php7.0-sp -i | grep -i sqlsrv" since I have php 7.0 running, but the return is "-bash: php7.0-sp: command not found". Only "php -i | grep sqlsrv" is working. Output see above in my original post.

Comment: Are you calling your script from the shell or via Apache? Apache and cli may use different php.ini files.

Comment: Thank you, that was a quite helpful comment. Indeed, they use different ini files. So I added the extensions to the ini file used by apache and voila: it is working